# Wordpress next/previous post id

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I'm trying to add the post id's to the next and previous posts. Currently using the following code gives me the undesired effect of post id of the page displayed.

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="project-tile nextproject">
    <a href="#"><?php next_post('%','', TRUE, '1'); ?></a></h2>
</div><!-- /project-tile -->

<div class="project-tile previousproject">
    <a href="#"><?php previous_post('%','', TRUE, '1'); ?></a>
</div><!-- /project-tile -->
```

Comment: It must be in the Loop to get the value. Seems like you are putting it when you are outside the loop? Share more info and code that what you are trying to achieve. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
// Works inside and outside of the Loop
function function_name() {
global $post;
$thePostID = $post->ID;
}
//or
echo $post->ID
```

Outside of the loop, use the post object [WP post ID outside of loop](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/getting-current-post-id-out-of-the-loop)
or you can use just the one call if you don't want to set up a function.

Comment: Thanks, not too sure how to implement this. Added it to my single.php and its returning syntax error

Comment: replace the_ID(); with echo $post->ID;

Comment: Added `<div id="post-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>` but still only adding the post of the current page. Is there something I've missed, unsure where I'm going wrong